# Getting W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have been sitting with this error for so long. I tried almost every solution available on the internet.
Most of the solutions were asking to try different versions of these lines. I am still getting the same error.

```
val recyclerview = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.memberRecyclerView)
        val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
val adapter = MemberListAdapter(data)
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)
```

It would be helpful if someone helps me figure out the issue. Thanks in advance!

AddingGroup.kt

```
class AddingGroup : Fragment() {
    //Declaring
    private lateinit var group_name : EditText
    private lateinit var member_email : EditText
    private lateinit var imageAdd1 : ImageView
    private lateinit var btn_submit : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adding_group, container, false)
        group_name = view.findViewById(R.id.group_name)
        member_email = view.findViewById(R.id.member_email)
        imageAdd1 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageAdd1)
        btn_submit = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit)
        val recyclerview = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.memberRecyclerView)
        val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        //adding member email to array list
        val data = ArrayList<MemberList>()
        imageAdd1.setOnClickListener{
            data.add(MemberList(member_email.toString(), R.drawable.ic_remove_circle));
        }
        val adapter = MemberListAdapter(data)
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)
        //adding group to firebase
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener {
            //
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

MemberListAdapter.kt

```
class MemberListAdapter(private val member_list: ArrayList<MemberList>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>()  {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return member_list.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_card, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val MemberList = member_list[position]

        // sets the image to the imageview from our itemHolder class
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(MemberList.removeBtn)

        // sets the text to the textview from our itemHolder class
        holder.textView.text = MemberList.memberEmail
    }

}

class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.removebtn)
    val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usermail)
}
```

Recyclerview:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/memberRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.288"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_group_card"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

fragment_group_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usermail"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="UserName"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/removebtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove_circle"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="350dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="6dp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout in fragment android studio using kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73285242/e-recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-in-fragment-android-studio)

Comment: `W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` is not an error. If that is your only symptom, and everything is working OK, ignore the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage empty conditions as per deletion of items

Can you change the fragment_group_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usermail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:hint="UserName"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/removebtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Other code looks fine only kotlin cleanup required for the code.

> recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager

> recyclerview.adapter = adapter